# How to do multiprocessing with shell commands using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I using two shell commands which almost take 2 hours to run sequentially, I want to run through the multiprocessing so that both can finish in one hour. The shell command I am using is:

```
os.system("mopac Zone.mop > Zone.out")
os.system("mopac Zone_sep.mop > Zone_sep.out")
```

Comment: why do u want to use python to execute the shell commands?

Comment: I'd agree with answer below that it's not clear if/why you need python at all here. But if you do, then `subprocess.run()` is probably what you're looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: it's an output of some previous compilation using python that's why I thought to use it.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()`, which *never* blocks to wait for something to finish unless you ask it to. I don't know why you think you need multiprocessing for this at all.

Answer (score 0):

in shell you can run them separately as `nohup`

`nohup mopac Zone.mop > Zone.out &`

`nohup mopac Zone_sep.mop > Zone_sep.out &`

These will run in parallel and you don't need python to execute them ...
`nohup` === `no hangup` , means your jobs will run until they terminate regardless of whether you log out of the shell session.

Comment: `nohup` isn't needed for that, the bash builtin `disown -h` is perfectly capable of doing the same thing. (Note that you'll want to also redirect both stdin and stderr explicitly; as in, `mopac Zone.map >Zone.out 2>&1 </dev/null & disown -h "$!"`)